# Geschlecht bei "dieser" und "jener"

Tags: pronoun, gender

Ich möchte folgendes schreiben:

> Ich glaube, du verwechselst Fleury und Fleurier. **Dieser** ist der Ort,
>   **jener** ein Familienname, nicht umgekehrt.

Ich bin aber unsicher darüber, welche Genera bei den Pronomen zu verwenden sind. Im ersten Satz sind ja nur zwei Eigennamen genannt, deren Bedeutung ja irgendwie unbekannt sind, und daher auch das Geschlecht unbekannt ist. Hier sind aber sowohl *Ort* als auch *Familienname* männlich und bieten wohl keine Probleme.

Was passiert aber, wenn es nicht so wäre? Verwendet man dann trotzdem Maskulinum, weil es sich um Namen handelt, und *Namen* ja maskulin sind? Richten sich diese Pronomina bezüglich des Geschlechts *zurück* oder *vorwärts*?

Wäre dieser Satz richtig?

> Ich glaube, du verwechselst Fleury und Fleurier. **Dieser** ist das
>   Schwimmbad, **jener** eine Friseurin.

Oder eher:

> Ich glaube, du verwechselst Fleury und Fleurier. **Dieses** ist das
>   Schwimmbad, **jene** eine Friseurin.

Comment: Sehr wahrscheinlich würde man das in modernem Deutsch nicht mit flektierten Demonstrativpronomen ausdrücken, deine Sätze hören sich deshalb ein bißchen holprig an. Wahrscheinlich würde man stattdessen "Das eine ist ein Schwimmbad, das andere die Friseurin" sagen.

Comment: Es kann sich schlecht vorwärts richten, denn da kann eine Verneinung stehen: "Bauer und Frau - dieser ist keine Bratpfanne, jene kein Bandscheibenvorfall." Bedeutung und Geschlecht haben auch oft keine funktionale Abhängigkeit: Der Ort, das Dorf, die Stadt; der Laden, das Geschäft; der Wissenschaftler, das Kommissionsmitglied, die Koryphäe usw. - derartiges Wissen hilft also nur gelegentlich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Flektion eines Demonstrativpronomens richtet sich nach dem Geschlecht dessen, worauf es sich bezieht.

In dem folgenden Beispiel ist der *Hund* maskulin und *Jenny* feminin. Da sich das Pronomen auf den Hund bezieht, muss es *der* heißen:

> Ich habe einen *Hund*. *Der* nennt sich Jenny.

Geht es um zwei Dinge, dann nutzt man *dieser* und *jener*. In dem folgenden Beispiel ist der *Hund* nach wie vor maskulin, weshalb es *dieser* heißen muss, aber die *Schildkröte* ist feminin, weshalb es *jene* heißen muss:

> Ich habe eine *Schildkröte* und einen *Hund*. *Dieser* nennt sich Jenny, *jene* heißt Felix.

Comment: Danke, es ist mir aber immernoch unklar, was denn passiert, wenn man Eigennamen im ersten Satz hat. Ist dies dann richtig: "Ich habe Jenny und Felix. Diese ist ein Hund und jener eine Schildkröte"?

Comment: Ja, denn _diese_ bezieht sich auf die feminine _Jenny_ und _jener_ auf den maskulinen _Felix_.

Comment: Ich sehe ich habe troztem falsch geschrieben, und die Ordnung vermischt, du hast es aber richtig verstanden. Es sollte also eher  "Ich habe Felix und Jenny. Diese ist ein Hund und jener eine Schildkröte" heissen. Was passiert aber wenn wir Ortsnamen oder andere Namen haben?

Comment: Äh, ja, das fällt mir auch gerade auf. Aber ich denke, wir verstehen uns :-). Möchtest du mit der Nachfrage über Ortsnamen oder anderen Namen wissen, was bei Dingen geschieht, bei denen das Geschlecht unbekannt ist? Ich würde dann zur Flektion gemäß dem Neutrum tendieren, also _dieses_ oder _jenes_, weiß aber nicht, ob es dafür eine Regel gibt.

Comment: Ja genau das wollte ich wissen :)

Answer (score 4):

Ich möchte das anhand von andern Wörtern abhandeln, die jeder kennt, und bei denen das grammatische Geschlecht jedem bekannt ist:

> Ich glaube, du verwechselst *Baum* und *Saum.*

Sowohl *Baum* als auch *Saum* sind männlich.

Muttersprachler würden hier nicht *»dieser«* und *»jener«* verwenden. Sie würden sagen:

> Ich glaube, du verwechselst *Baum* und *Saum.* **Das eine** ist eine Pflanze, **das andere** ist ein genähter Rand eines Kleidungsstückes.

Hier passiert etwas, das sonst im deutschen unüblich ist: Alle unbelebten Dinge werden behandelt, als wären sie sächlich. Bei Personen ist das nicht der Fall:

> Ich glaube, du verwechselst *Walter* mit *Hans.* **Der eine** hat dichtes Haar, **der andere** hat eine Glatze.
>
> Ich glaube, du verwechselst *Ilse* mit *Eva.* **Die eine** ist ein Kind, **die andere** ist erwachsen.

Das macht es auch einfach, wenn es um unbelebte Dinge geht, deren grammatisches Geschlecht man nicht kennt (alle Substantive im folgenden Beispiel sind frei erfundene Wärter ohne Bedeutung):

> Ich glaube, du verwechselst *Traket* und *Molb.* **Das eine** ist ein Dram, **das andere** ist eine Uluse.

Bei *Dram* kann man aufgrund des Artikels auf ein männliches oder sächliches Wort schließen, *Uluse* muss offensichtlich weiblich sein. Aber *Traket* und *Molb* könnten jedes beliebige Geschlecht haben.

---

Wenn es unbedingt *dieser* und *jener* sein soll, muss das grammatische Geschlecht aber übereinstimmen:

> Ich glaube, du verwechselst *Baum* und *Saum.* **Dieser** ist eine Pflanze, **jener** ist ein genähter Rand eines Kleidungsstückes.

Nachdem das Pronomen *dieser* auf den *Baum* verweist, muss *dieser* dasselbe Geschlecht wie *Baum* haben, also männlich sein. Womit dieser Baum dann in der Gleichsetzung verglichen wird, ist irrelevant. In einer Gleichsetzung spielen die Geschlechter keine Rolle:

> Der Baum ist eine Pflanze.

Sowohl *Baum* als auch *Pflanze* haben jeweils ihr eigenes unveränderbares Geschlecht, und die beiden Geschlechter sind verschieden. Ersetz man eines dieser Wörter durch ein Pronomen, muss das Pronomen, das ja als Platzhalter fungiert, genau das Geschlecht jenes Wortes haben, an dessen Platz es steht. Dabei ist auch egal, ob das referenzierte Substantiv davor oder dahinter steht.

Steht das Ziel der Referenz vor dem Pronomen, nennt man das eine *Anapher*:

> **Prinz Philip** ging in Pension. **Er** war 70 Jahre lang im Amt.

Steht es dahinter, spricht man von einer *Katapher*:

> *(Einmoderation eines Fernsehsprechers in einer Nachrichtensendung:)*
>   »**Er** war 70 Jahre lang im Amt, ist jetzt 96 Jahre alt, und ging gestern in Pension. Die Rede ist von **Prinz Philip, dem Duke of Edinburgh.**«

Comment: Danke Hubert für die Antwort. Ich bin darüber bewusst, dass man "dieser und jener" beim Sprechen gewöhnlich nicht verwendet, und habe daher in meiner Frage das Wort "sagen" weggenommen.  Ich kenne auch die Verwendung von "das eine und das andere", und bin eigentlich nur in "dieser-jener" interessiert. Ich habe nicht richtig begriffen welche von meinen Sätzen dann richtig wäre. Weiter glaube ich, dass du im Satz mit Baum und Saum die Pronomina verwechselt hast. "Dieser" sollte sich wohl auf "Saum" beziehen, und "jener" auf "Baum", oder?

Comment: @Beta: Warum glaubst du, "dieser" sollte sich auf "Saum" beziehen, und "jener" auf "Baum"?

Comment: Weil Saum das nähere Wort ist und Baum ferner weg steht. So habe ich es gelernt, ist das also falsch?

Comment: @Beta: Man kann auch sagen "**Dieser** Baum ist eine Eiche und **jener** (Baum) ist eine Buche", obwohl viele Leute, die ich kenne, eher sagen würden: "**Der** Baum **hier** ist eine Eiche und **der** (Baum) **da** ist eine Buche". "Dieser" und "jener" werden in täglichen Sprachgebrauch selten benutzt. Sie klingen m.E. etwas "geschwollen".

Comment: @Beta: Ich habe das nicht so gelernt, jedenfalls nicht in Bezug auf die Entfernung der Wörter im Satz. Ich habe gelernt, dass die Entfernung der Gegenstände im Raum, also der räumliche Abstand zum Sprecher entscheidend ist. Wenn sich der Sprecher gerade an den Baum lehnt, der Saum sich aber am Kleid einer Frau in Japan befindet, dann verweist »dieser« auf den Baum, und »jener« auf den Saum. ...

Comment: ... Da es hier aber nicht um konkrete Gegenstände handelt, sondern um allgemeine Abstraktionen, denen kein bestimmter Aufenthaltsort zugeschrieben werden kann, ist meiner Meinung nach die Verwendung von *dieser* und *jener* ohnehin nicht sinnvoll, weswegen man eher von *dem einen* und *dem anderen* sprechen sollte.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: »Der Baum **da**«, wenn ein weiter entfernt stehender Baum gemeint ist, funktioniert nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum. Im Süden (Österreich, und vermutlich auch Bayern) *muss* es »der Baum **dort**« heißen. Im Süden unterscheidet man viel strenger zwischen *da* und *dort* als weiter im Norden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, es gehört zwar nicht zum Thema, aber finde das mit dem _da_ und _dort_ interessant. Worin besteht der Unterschied, auf den man im Süden strenger achte?

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass es einen regionalen Unterschied in der Verwendung von "da" und "dort" gibt - So, wie ich das sehe, ist "da" immer dem Sprecher näher als "dort".

Comment: @tofro: Das stimmt schon. Aber wenn ich zwei Bäume habe, wovon einer *hier* ist, und der andere offenbar *nicht hier* (also etwas weiter weg), dann scheint es in Deutschland in Ordnung zu sein, genau das zu sagen, was Rudy geschrieben hat, nämlich: »Der Baum hier ist eine Eiche und der Baum **da** ist eine Buche.« In Österreich gilt aber genau dieser Gebrauch von *»da«* als falsch. In Österreich *muss* es heißen: »... der Baum **dort** ist eine Buche.« Das wäre natürlich auch in D richtig, aber in D ist *»dort«* eine von 2 erlaubten Möglichkeiten, in Ö ist es die einzige erlaubte Möglichkeit.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Kommentare sind nicht der richtige Ort um Fragen zu stellen. Der richtige Ort ist hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Kennt das österreichische Deutsch den Ausdruck "hier und da" (so wie "hin und wieder")? Das sollte nach deiner Erklärung bei dir dann ja was anderes bedeuten...

Comment: @tofro: Ich kenne nur *»[hie und da](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hie_und_da)«* (»hie« ohne R) im Sinn von »hin und wieder; manchmal«, aber einerseits ist das erste Wort ein anderes (obwohl es, wie ich vermute, durchaus mit »hier« verwandt ist), und andererseits ist das eine Redewendung. Redewendungen zeichnen sich dadurch aus, dass der Sinn der ganzen Phrase oftmals nur wenig mit dem Sinn der einzelnen Wörter zu tun hat. (Wenn jemand z.B. »aus allen Wolken fällt«, findet nur selten lebensbedrohlicher Sturz statt.)